# Can I use `git subtree split` to maintain a "fork" of a project's subdirectory?

Tags: git, version-control, open-source, git-subtree

In short, I want to "fork" a subdirectory of another project (not under my control) to the top-level of a new repository and make enhancements to the code in that subdirectory while preserving the ability to merge in changes from the subdirectory in the upstream project.

I've been reading up on this topic for a while now but can't find a sure answer for my situation. Most of the uses of `git subtree` break down into these cases:

- A subdirectory of a project is being spun off as its own separate project. The parent project is removing the subdirectory entirely and the new project lives its own life.
- A maintainer of a parent project wants to allow maintenance of a subdirectory on its own terms and spins it off into its own repository, which is added back to the main project using `git subtree add`

These use cases don't apply to me: I'm not forking-and-forgetting, and I don't own both sides of this fork, so the `git subtree add` flow isn't applicable.

So let's say the original module lives in `contrib/foo` in the main project. My current idea is to:

- Use `git subtree split -P contrib/foo -b upstream_vx.y` to create a new history that "hoists" the subdirectory up to the top-level of a repository
- Create a `master` branch from my project with enhancements from this point
- Keep updating `upstream_vx.y` by running `git subtree split` occasionally
- When I need a bug fix or whatnot from upstream, merge `upstream_vx.y` into my `master`

This doesn't feel "git-like" to me. Specifically, I'm basically creating a parallel history of the upstream project's subdirectory and maintaining my own "hoisted" branch for each major upstream branch (to say nothing of being able to reference upstream tags).

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: The "usual use case" I mention is described [here](http://adhipg.in/notes/creating-sub-repositories-from-your-git-repository/), i.e. split off a subdir and add it to the main project using `git subtree add`. I _think_ the last paragraph [here](http://blog.charlescy.com/blog/2013/08/17/git-subtree-tutorial/) is discussing what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have been maintaining a similar situation to you.  I have a primary project (ProjA) which has modules, and I am adding a subtree of a second project (ProjB) into the primary's modules.  In order to accomplish this, I maintain a copy ProjB.

Split ProjB:

```
cd ProjB
git checkout -b split-maint
git subtree split --prefix=important/dir --branch=module-for-A
```

Add the subtree to ProjA:

```
cd ProjA
git remote add ProjB_remote /path/to/ProjB
git fetch ProjB_remote
git subtree add --prefix=modules/projB_mod ProjB_remote/module-for-A --message="commit message"
```

Then to update/maintain, re-split the original (as above).  The key here is **git subtree split is repeatable**, and the SHA of each revision that was previously split will be the same.

Update ProjA with the new details:

```
cd ProjA
git fetch ProjB_remote
git subtree merge --prefix=modules/projB_mod ProjB_remote/module-for-A --message="commit message"
```

Technically I do it slightly differently because my ProjB has a lot of commits and the split actually takes an hour to run.  I can give you details on how to help with that too if you need it.  (Just comment, and I will update this answer).

Comment: See the comment I added to my question: Your use-case is the typical one, i.e. you're forking a subdir of ProjA into a new ProjB and want to pull changes from ProjB back into ProjA in the future.

Comment: I want to fork a third-party ProjA's subdirectory to my own project. ProjA will continue developing the subdirectory as normal (they will never add me as a subtree), but I want to be able to pull in bugfixes, etc. from them in the future.

Comment: Yes, that is the subtree merge.  You could make your own changes to the local subtree fork (ProjA), then on ProjB, you would fetch and re-split their updates. Then you do the subtree merge to put the new ProjB changes into ProjA.

Comment: As stated, I do not own ProjA, nor do I have commit privileges, nor will they desire to merge back in my changes. I am taking one of their subdirectories and turning into a separate project, but wish to merge in their changes to that subdirectory in a clean way. I do not have permission to add my project as a subtree in their project, nor will they be using subtrees: they will continue development in the original subdirectory as before.